# error: incompatible types possible lossy conversion from float to char

Tags: java

I am working on this Project for an hour and I still can`t find a solution. I am always getting the same error(EnigmaEncrypt.java:44: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from float to char
        char e = exampleCharInput;
                 ^
1 error) 
Here is my Code :

```
 import java.util.Scanner;



// Created by ab38 on 2015-12-01.

public class EnigmaEncrypt {

     // Static Scanner field

    private static Scanner scan;

    /**
     * Get a char from the command line.
     *
     * @return the first char of the current line, typed by the user
     * on the command line.
     */
    private static char getChar() {
        return scan.next().charAt(0);
    }

    /**
     * Get an integer from the command line.
     *
     * @return the integer on the current line, typed by the user
     * on the command line.
     */
    private static int getInt() {
        return scan.nextInt();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Example: How to get an integer from the command line:
        System.out.println("Enter an integer:");
        int exampleIntInput = getInt();
        System.out.println("Rotorposition: " + exampleIntInput);


        // Example: How to get a single char from the command line:
        System.out.println("Enter a single character:");
        float exampleCharInput = getChar() + exampleIntInput;
        char e = exampleCharInput;

        System.out.println("Char from command line: " + e);


    }
}
```

Comment: "I still can't find a solution":  Which problem are you trying to solve? I assume it has to do with encryption, but please spell it out. Also, you're assigning a float to a char -- why? What is that char meant to signify?

Comment: You're assigning the sum of an int and a char to a float -- why?  What is that sum meant to signify?

Comment: When you add a `char` to an `int`, the result is an `int`.  You then try to assign it to a `char`.  That is a "possibly lossy conversion", because for some values of the expression the assignment would "chop" significant bits from the high end of the value.

Answer (score 0):

char are stored in 2bytes while float in 4bytes. you're trying to put a float in a char without doing a casting. try this instead

```
char e = (char) exampleCharInput;
```